# Making list columns while looping through data?

Tags: c#, loops, ienumerable, modulo

I've always wanted to ask this. Let's say in C# I've got an `IEnumerable<Cars>` that contains 20 results from a LINQ query to my SQL database.

I want to list it into 4 columns of 5, using `ul` tags. What I usually end up doing is starting the first `ul`, then `foreach` through the enumerable, keep a counter inside that when it's `% 5 == 0` I close a `ul` and start a new one... after the `foreach`, add a final closing `ul`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy()` to group the cars together the way you want to present them, in your case have groups of 5 cars together (using integer division so cars with index 0 to 4 will be in group 1, index 5 to 9 in group 2, etc):

```
 List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
 //populate cars

 var carGroups = cars.Select((car, index) => new { Index = index, Car = car })
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 5)
                     .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Car).ToList())
                     .ToList();

    foreach (var group in carGroups)
    {
        //Emit <UL>
        foreach (var car in group)
        {
            //Emit <LI> with car details
        }
        //Emit </UL>
    }
```

Comment: Very nice... I like that. What about if you wanted to put a heading above each `ul` that showed the name of the group? Is it available in that group?

Comment: @Chad: what would you define as name of the group?

Comment: Maybe something like grouping by Car.Make... (Honda, Toyota, GMC, Ford, etc...)

Comment: @Chad: You could certainly modify it that way, but then you are not ensured anymore that each group has 5 cars - just remove the both `Select()` (not needed in this case) and change the GroupBy to `.GroupBy(x => x.Make)`

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that. Thanks for your answers, learned a lot. I really appreciate that.